# What is the absolute ultimate subject (like math, literature, etc)?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, knowledge, idea

Seems like all subjects are branches of more general subject. Pretty much all sciences seem to find their roots in physics but physics is just math. There are many branches of math but still all just math. Everything seems to be math which leads me to believe math is the ultimate subject. Then theres art and literature. Plenty about art and literature is mathematical in nature but it doesn't seem to explain it all, which leads to philosophy. Its been said all pages on wikipedia lead to philosophy. (even math leads to philosophy).* Could math just be philosophy? It seems like philosophy was the beginnings of real math (like not arithmetic or counting) (is there a name for this? Do you get what I mean? Mathematics seems to be all encompassing including arithmetic, counting, etc but Seemed to be the right name, idk.). So that leads me to believe that philosophy is the root of all subjects. But while thinking about this I kept thinking about logic. Logic is awesome. I've been taking a lot of computer science courses and it was surprising how much is just about logic. In fact it seem like math and philosophy are all basically just logic. But is logic a subject? Seems like most people just throw logic under either math or philosophy.

(* my main point here is that wikipedia is a massive encyclopedia made up by just tons and tons of people. I doubt there was a plan to make everything basically lead to philosophy but since that is what seems to happen more often then not, perhaps that is the way things are in real life. Kinda like a sample in statistics.)

What do you guys think? These are a condensed versions of my thoughts. **Please open my mind to new thoughts and ideas!** (Perhaps everything is just thought but thats metaphysics and metaphysics is just philosophy ;) )
Thanks so much for your time!

Comment: I read that if you follow every link on Wikipedia, it eventually refers back to Philosophy. Perhaps it's true.

Comment: Yes I did mention that. Its an interesting thought

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a bit of an opinion question, so I will give you mine.

Physics, mathematics, and philosophy are three fields of axiomatic study from which all other fields of knowledge arise.  They are distinguished by their constraints (boundary conditions).

- Mathematics has no constraints on either the initial axioms or the derived conclusions.  However, branches of mathematics are not useful unless they can be used by either philosophers or physicists.
- Philosophy has the constraints that one must agree with its axioms, but are forced to accept its conclusions.  This is only true in principle since in practice we question the axioms of philosophies with heinous outcomes.
- Physics has constraints on its conclusions, namely that they must agree with observation.  There are no constraints on its axioms; take, for example, string theory.

Comment: I disagree that this is basically all opinion but thanks for your answer